# find number of points closer to lines inside a polygon ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have a map that contains 3 shapefiles representing projects (points), studies performed (lines) and sectors (polygons). I would like to know how can I find the sector (polygon) that contains the higher number of projects (points) closer to the studies performed (lines). See image.

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This has many equally valid possible solutions, which makes it less than ideal for the GIS SE Q&A format.

Comment: Well I had no idea what to do. I am new user and I am learning on my own that's why I had no clue even how to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Select By Location** tool to select those points within your chosen distance of the lines. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000072000000

This will create a new layer just containing the points you are interested in.

Then you can use a **Spatial Join** to find out how many of these relevant points are in each of your polygons.
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000

For this Spatial Join your target feature will be the polygon layer and your join feature will be the newly created relevant points layer.

The new layer created by the Spatial Join will automatically include a Count field which records the number of points in each polygon. Look at this layers attribute table to see the count.